# rake background task can not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background, rake

I want to use rake background task in rails like this

```
system("cd #{Rails.root} && RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} rake abc:def --trace 2>&1 >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &")
```

This is ok in development environment, but will not work in production mode.

I used logger to check whether the command string is generated ok or not, but it seems every things is fine in production evironment:

```
cd /home/username/rails_staging/Abc/releases/20100904034630 && RAILS_ENV=production rake abc:def --trace 2>&1 >> /home/username/rails_staging/Abc/releases/20100904034630/log/rake.log &
```

Any body has any ideas about why this can not work in production mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my test setup to replicate your problem.

```
# lib/tasks/whatever.rake
namespace :abc do
  task :def do
    puts "DEF ran in #{Rails.env} mode in the directory #{Rails.root}."
  end
end

$ rake abc:def
DEF ran in development mode in the directory /tmp/boluapp

$ RAILS_ENV=production rake abc:def
DEF ran in production mode in the directory /tmp/bobluapp.
```

It will run.  It's just not going to the log.  You can see it run here in the `rails console` running in production mode.

```
>> system("cd #{Rails.root} && RAILS_ENV=#{Rails.env} rake abc:def --trace 2>&1 /tmp/rake.log")
** Invoke abc:def (first_time)
** Execute abc:def
DEF ran in production mode in the directory /tmp/boluapp.
```

Rake disables logging in production mode.  So create a new one.

```
# lib/tasks/whatever.rb
namespace :abc do
  task :def do
    logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/rake.log")
    logger.level = Logger::INFO
    logger.info "DEF ran in #{Rails.env} mode in the directory #{Rails.root}."
  end
end

$ RAILS_ENV=production rake abc:def
$ cat log/rake.log
# Logfile created on 2011-11-23 00:00:00 -0500 by logger.rb/31641
DEF ran in production mode in the directory /tmp/boluapp.
```

As a side note of free advice you probably don't want, this is a bad way to run background jobs.  Look at the delayed_job gem.

Comment: more free advice, resque gem.